# Find out which app is using Bluetooth device

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I noticed that my MacBook is connected to my Kevo bluetooth lock.  This lock is supposed to connect with an iOS app, but there is no macOS app that I'm aware of, and I have never told my computer to pair with it.  I want to figure out why it's connected to my laptop and what data has been exchanged.  I tried `log show --last 24h | grep Kevo` but that shows nothing.  That's interesting, since there are lines in the log mentioning my trackpad by name every time it connects.  I'm just updated to High Sierra 10.13.5, and I never noticed this happening before on Sierra.

Edit:  After disconnecting the Kevo in the dropdown menu, it disappeared, so I am no longer able to reconnect to it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes your iCloud account will share Bluetooth authentications across iOS and macOS devices for easier pairing. Take for instance AirPods will automatically show up in your Mac after you've paired them with your iPhone. You used to be able to turn this off in the iCloud settings -> Documents and Data option.

Comment: Yes I assume it must be iCloud-related, but I don't think the computer should pair with the device all by itself just because the authentication was shared.

Comment: It would be part of the iCloud implementation with the app. I would suggest that you contact the app developer https://www.kwikset.com/Customer-Support/Product-FAQs/New-Case.aspx and Apple https://www.apple.com/feedback/